# Not getting GUI after rc.local execution in Centos6.6

Tags: centos6, rc.local, centos6.6

This is CentOS 6.6 server with GUI. I have place my startup commands in /etc/rc.local The service running on this server are Docker and Nginx. So I have put Container start up command with port mapping in rc.local.

The Docker Containers are starting but on Server I am not getting GUI, only CLI is coming, if I comment all the commands in rc.local then GUI is coming after reboot.

The rc.local file contains...

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.
# You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't
# want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.

touch /var/lock/subsys/local

sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
sleep 5
setenforce Permissive
sleep 5
iptables -F
sleep 5
service nginx stop
sleep 5
service nginx start
sleep 5
service docker stop
sleep 5
service docker start
sleep 5
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
sleep 5
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
sleep 5
docker run -p port:port/tcp -d memcached:latest
sleep 5
docker run -d  -v /mnt/path:/mnt/path -p port:port/tcp   imagename
sleep 5
docker run -d  -p port:port/tcp -p port:port/udp imagename
sleep 5
mount -t nfs 192.168.0.3:/mnt/path/ /mnt/path/
```

Comment: What is all that doing there? None of that belongs in rc.local! Set up your services and mount points in the normal method.

Comment: I want to achieve something which will automatically starts my services on reboot....the simplest thing which I found on google was to place in rc.local

Comment: 90% of the tutorials in the Internet are wrong or have bad advice. You read one such page. You automatically start a service at boot by enabling it, e.g. `chkconfig nginx on`.

Comment: What if I want to start other things than any service like a docker container after reboot

Comment: having same issue as http://serverfault.com/questions/482860/centos-stopped-loading-after-i-added-something-to-etc-rc-d-rc-local

Answer (score 1):

Something in your `rc.local` isn't terminating.  Execution of this file has to finish before the regular boot process completes, and X is started.

Since you say the docker containers all start up, my guess would be the `mount` line isn't completing for some reason.  Confirm that it isn't, find out why, and fix it.  Better yet, move all that stuff out of `rc.local` and into proper startup files, as Michael recommends, not least because all those `sleep`s will make boot take a minute longer than it should.